# Xamarin.Forms application properties not saved between sessions with Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

In my cross-platform app I save application properties in the following way:

```
Application.Current.Properties["myValue"] = "Test";
await Application.Current.SavePropertiesAsync();
```

I then retrieve them later like this:

```
string myVal = Application.Current.Properties["myValue"];
```

This works perfectly when using the Android emulator. I can close the emulator down, and when I restart it again, my app data is preserved.

However, when I deploy this app to a physical Android device, data preservation works as expected until I close the app and open it again. At this point I retrieve an empty value. It's as though the data is only saved to memory (and not to file).

Furthermore, the iOS version of the exact same app works faultlessly. When I open the app up, all previous values have been saved and I can retrieve them.

What am I doing wrong on the Android version? Is there an Android setting, permission, or option which I need to enable to have the values saved between app sessions when actually deployed to a phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't remember exactly which part of this solved the issue, but when I followed the instructions to prepare the Android application for release from start to finish, the issue went away. The problem occurred when debug builds were used on an Android device.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_1_-_preparing_an_application_for_release/

The link details the suggested settings for the Android project when releasing to device. Following these instructions should solve the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem where only the debug version saved Properties. I think we're still waiting for the bug fix, and this is the workaround [on Xamarin Forms bugzilla](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=36697#c11).

In short: go to `.Droid project settings -> Android Options -> Linker`
and enter/add `"System.Runtime.Serialization"` to Skip linking assemblies.

Answer (score 2):

Wow! After lots of research, I have getting solution for same issue in mine. Problem is that, when i store List or DataTable in Application.Current.Properties then all properties are removed after reopen app but if i store List or DataTable as serialize, it working fine.

Answer (score 0):

In VS you need to enable the option:

> Preserve application data/cache on device between deploys

You can find this at Tools > Options > Xamarin > Android Settings.

Comment: Thanks - just to confirm - the problem occurs when actually deployed to an Android device (via Google Play etc). The app behaves as it should using the emulator. Data is preserved between sessions. I have updated my question to clarify this.

Comment: If you can't solve this, have a look at [Xamarin.Plugins.Settings](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Plugins/tree/master/Settings).

Comment: That option is enabled, bug still occurs :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this has stopped in the latest updates of Xamarin Forms, the data is available until the application is running similar to session but persistent storage does not work.

The best api I think available for this is Akavache https://github.com/akavache/Akavache.

You can read this blog https://codemilltech.com/akavache-is-aka-awesome/.

Update 
There is a bug filed in bugzilla:
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=26444